# .swp file size increasing automatically, why?

Tags: linux, vim

I want to ask reasons for `swp` file for instance generated by `vim` increasing its size automatically.

What could possibly be the reasons / factors of size being increased?

Comment: keep tracking of what is going on...

Comment: Related - [What causes swap files to be created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27923/100397)

Comment: CLOSE-VOTERS: Too broad? Be so kind as to explain why so.

Answer (score 1):

The `swp` file contains all the changes since the edit session began. This allows the editor to manage not only rollbacks (undo operations) but also to replay changes forward from the unchanged file (`vim -r`).

Inevitably, as you continue to make edits the file size has to grow to contain then.